# Is there a way to specify what properties an NSArrayController should fetch for an entity?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data

I have an NSArrayController that returns to me an array of NSManagedObjects, however I'm only interested in displaying certain attributes of those objects in an NSTableView and I don't need all of them. Is there a way to have the NSArrayController only fetch certain properties, similar to how you can have an NSFetchRequest only retrieve certain properties?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.  A `NSFetchRequest` can return dictionaries with a subset of data, a `NSArrayController` will always return objects which will be fully populated.